# XNA Texture Is Cut When Drawing Several Billboard

Tags: xna

I'm creating an array of billboards, set animated textures with transparent to each of it then orbit the camera around those billboards. Problem is in some point at orbit degree looks the texture of billboards behind the front of it is cut as seen in here:

http://img815.imageshack.us/img815/3956/questionpic02.jpg

How to fix it?

Please kindly answer, thank you

Comment: you don't really belive someone can fix code by being shown a problem in the output from that code, do you? Show your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you happen to be drawing the closer billboard first?

If so, then when the GPU gets around to drawing the next one, the depth buffer culls those pixels that underlap because it thinks they are behind something. At that stage, the GPU doesn't differentiate between transparent & opaque.

If you think this may be your problem, sort your billboards from back to front and draw them in that order.under

Comment: Hi I'm trying to set CullNone to GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState, but still the same, try reverse the order of rendering those billboards but still the same :(

Comment: I'm drawing 4 billboards with only X axis different, then orbit camera around them while always translate those billboards matrices so each of  it always face the camera. On starting of orbit everything went just fine, until about after 225 degree the problem start to occure

Comment: the CullNone is for vertices in the vertex shader, not pixels in the pixel shader. It appeared to me that it was culling the pixels in the pixel shader pipeline which is a depth buffer operation. But if you are POSITIVE that you are drawing the farthest away one first and the next farthest 2nd... etc. then that's probably not the correct diagnosis anyway.

Comment: Also, verify that your graphics.GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;